# Can I have different virtual desktops with different resolutions/scaling?

Tags: resolution, display

I'm really frustrated by the way some applications are not HiDPI aware and resort to pixel doubling - video games, GIMP, etc.

Is it possible to have one of my virtual desktops (I think apple uses a different term? "Workspaces"?) be at the native resolution (ie "scaled" to "more space") while the other remain at "best for this display"?

I've done a tonne of searching and I can't find anything, but maybe it's just hurt by the fact I don't know the apple jargon.

I'd be happy with something like windows has that allows me to turn off DPI scaling for specific applications.

I have a 2014 Macbook Pro 15" retina with a 2880x1800 resolution.

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: I was wondering the same and it should offer that. I am tired of switching resolutions because some apps are too small to read. It would be so nice if I can view at different resolution with a simple swipe on my Trackpad to swipe spaces!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, each Desktop (Space) will have the same resolution, whatever the Display's resolution is set at.

You could use an App like [Display Menu](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/display-menu/id549083868?mt=12) to more easily/quickly change the resolution as needed/wanted as you change between Desktops.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not keen to hot-swap resolutions since I don't like all the apps shifting around; I'd rather stick with the current crappy pixel doubling.

Edit: I'll mark your answer as The Answer after a few more days of vain hope that someone has another suggestion.